# Is it possible to develop phonegap application using Material Design (Polymer) for lower version of android 4.3 and less

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, material-design

I try to develop Phonegap Application using Material Design (Polymer).
I Follow https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/ Example And I get success to create an application, but the problem is that when I test my application in my Samsung TAB (Android 4.4) Material Design working Fine, when I test my application in my Samsung Mobile (Android 4.1) Material Design does not work.

Samsung TAB (Android 4.4)
[image: Samsung TAB (Android 4.4)]
Samsung Mobile (Android 4.1)
[image: Samsung Mobile (Android 4.1)]

I need to know that Polymer support only android 4.4 and above??????

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the browser used for the webview on older versions of Android are old as dirt.  You could consider using [the Crosswalk Project.](https://crosswalk-project.org/.)

**For Cordova 3.x:**

Crosswalk works quite well with Cordova, and it is easy to merge an existing Cordova application with Crosswalk.  See the [instructions here.](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_3/migrate_an_application.html) Crosswalk also solves a few other issues with the old as dirt webkit, including performance improvements, flexbox support, shadow dom support, and a host of other features projects like polymer use.

**For Cordova 4.x:**

Cordova 4+ supports plugable webviews, and Crosswalk currently works for iOS and Android versions of Cordova 4.x.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova build [ios | android]
```

Answer (score 2):

Polymer not support old versions of the HTML/JS/CSS engine... Polymer support Chrome engine (Not based on webkit) https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html